# Website works in the browser, but weird problems with nameservers and google bot

Tags: nameserver, google

I've moved a website, nextblog.ro, to a VPS, 3 days ago. After 12 hours aprox, I could see my website working on the new server, and apparently everyone in my town can access it.

My first problem is that I noticed it does not appears no more in search results, also nameservers never propagate in some areas.

So when I try to access my website "as google bot" from google webmaster tools, I get this

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2011 20:04:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
X-Pingback: http://nextblog.ro/xmlrpc.php
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2ad0d5c892ee9df04b0950e37c0ec40d; path=/
Set-Cookie: bp-message=deleted; expires=Sun, 05-Sep-2010 20:04:40 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bp-message-type=deleted; expires=Sun, 05-Sep-2010 20:04:40 GMT; path=/
Last-Modified: Mon, 05 Sep 2011 20:04:41 GMT
Location: http://nextblog.ro
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And "Content-Length: 0" that scares me the most - means google bot can't get anything on my website? Right! The website seems all right, as I can acces all features from any browser, I have a robots.txt file also, allowing all user-agents...

So why Google bot fails?

-------------- Later Edit ---------------------

I noticed the server sends a header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked", may this be the problem?

Comment: I have also checked another website on the same server with google bot. It worked fine - so no error in webserver configuration.

Comment: I have also find that static html files are parsed ok by google bot. only php files seems to be buggy...

Comment: Also Yahoo! and Bing seems to crawl my website just fine... .

Answer (score 0):

A content length of 0 is to be expected for a 302 response; whichever resource the google bot is requesting is redirecting it to `http://nextblog.ro`.

Why this is happening is impossible to tell without knowing your web server's configuration and which resource is being requested.

Comment: My website was served as compressed gzip, on the old server, while now it's not compressed no more. Could google penalized me for serving another content-type now... ?

Comment: @adrian7 While they do factor in page load speed, it's unlikely that it has made any difference.  Are they able to successfully follow the 302 to a valid page, then...?

Comment: As I've said, I have moved my website to another server... . So where should I redirect... . Domain is the same nextblog.ro, urls are the same. The only thing that changed is the nameservers and nameserver's IPs. My only clue is that google didn't cach up with this and is still looking for my website on the old server, where it's possible to have a 301 or 302 response header. Also I have checked with dig, ping the domain seems to be all right on my side. Also when checked with live http headers, the headers I get are different from the ones google receives...